In swiftui, there are multiple buttons of the same listitem, why does the contextmenu not take effect?
I am a swiftui beginner, and there is a problem that has been bothering me. Multiple buttons on the same list item, why does the contextmenu not take effect? I want the button have the context menu not list item.  the code is below:
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List{
            Section("标签"){
                HStack(alignment: .top,spacing: 5) {
                    Text("hello")
                        .contextMenu(menuItems: {
                            Button(role:.destructive) {// not working
                                // todo add action code
                                } label: {
                                    Label("删除1", systemImage: "trash")
                            }
                        })
                        .padding(5)
                        .background(.blue)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .cornerRadius(5.0)
                    Text("world")
                        .contextMenu(menuItems: {       // not working
                            Button(role:.destructive) {
                                // todo add action code
                                } label: {
                                    Label("删除2", systemImage: "trash")
                            }
                        })
                        .padding(5)
                        .background(.blue)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .cornerRadius(5.0)
                                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

enter image description here
I want button of "hello" and "world" have contextmenu property , when user long press different button have different menu, even if the two buttons are in the same list item

This will work if you replace List with VStack so the issue seems to be with List.

Yeah multiple context menus inside List don't work unfortunately. You can use a LazyVStack instead.
